# Locus of point moving with circle

Tags: coordinate-systems, locus

Consider the circle of radius $1$ unit with its centre at the point $(0,1)$. From the initial position, the circle is rolled along the positive $x$- axis without slipping. Find the locus of the point $P$ on the circumference of the circle which is on the origin at the initial position of the circle.

I had been trying to calculate position of point after circle moves t units but to no avail. Any help will be very helpful.

Comment: Cycloid. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid

Comment: Fantastic, but what is the proof of the stated locus?

Comment: It almost looks like the question is asking about the radians needed to travel to get a circle to roll so that its edge and center swap positions.  If so, then the center has moved by $r$ the radius of the circle, and this is also the count of radians rolled.